# GDB Setting Trap Flag After Popf (possible bug?)

Tags: gdb

Take a look:

```
    (gdb) x/x $esp
       0xb720a621:  0x00000000
    (gdb) info register eflags
       eflags         0x200286  [ PF SF IF ID ]
    (gdb) x/5i $pc
    => 0x15a965d <tables+11901>:    popf   
       0x15a965e <tables+11902>:    mov    $0xd7fb0aa3,%ecx
       0x15a9663 <tables+11907>:    ret    $0x849d
       0x15a9666 <tables+11910>:    xor    (%ebx),%esi
       0x15a9668 <tables+11912>:    aam    $0x78
    (gdb) stepi
       0x015a965e in tables () from /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
    (gdb) info register eflags
       eflags         0x202 [ IF ]
    (gdb) stepi
       0x015a9663 in tables () from /usr/local/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
    (gdb) info register eflags
       eflags         0x302 [ TF IF ]
```

Not sure why TF is set after the next instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is a kernel bug. The kernel has to set `TF` when single-stepping but user mode also may be modifying `TF`. To handle this, the kernel tries to maintain who set `TF`:

```c
    /* Set TF on the kernel stack.. */
    regs->flags |= X86_EFLAGS_TF;

    /*
     * ..but if TF is changed by the instruction we will trace,
     * don't mark it as being "us" that set it, so that we
     * won't clear it by hand later.
     *
     * Note that if we don't actually execute the popf because
     * of a signal arriving right now or suchlike, we will lose
     * track of the fact that it really was "us" that set it.
     */
    if (is_setting_trap_flag(child, regs)) {
            clear_tsk_thread_flag(child, TIF_FORCED_TF);
            return 0;
    }
```

Note it even admits some corner cases might make it lose track.
What's worse is that `is_setting_trap_flag` only checks if the instruction will modify `TF`, it doesn't check if it is actually setting it:

```c
    switch (opcode[i]) {
    /* popf and iret */
    case 0x9d: case 0xcf:
            return 1;
```

As such it will mark `TF` as user-set even if it has been cleared. In `get_flags` it will try to mask `TF` if it was set by kernel as follows:

```c
    /*
     * If the debugger set TF, hide it from the readout.
     */
    if (test_tsk_thread_flag(task, TIF_FORCED_TF))
            retval &= ~X86_EFLAGS_TF;
```

Since `TIF_FORCED_TF` has been erroneously cleared, this condition will not be true, hence the `TF` that has in fact been set by the kernel for single-stepping will be returned to the debugger.

I think this can be fixed by modifying `is_setting_trap_flag` so that it checks the stack for the new value of the flags and only returns `1` if `TF` is actually being set.